# "Invalid hook call" when mocking React HOC with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

I'm using [react-speech-recognition](https://github.com/FoundersFactory/react-speech-recognition) to transcribe speech to text in my React app. react-speech-recognition provides the `SpeechRecognition` higher-order component, which injects additional properties like `browserSupportsSpeechRecognition` into wrapped components.

My App component looks like this:

```
// src/App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition';

const App = ({ transcript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`transcript changed: ${transcript}`);
    }, [transcript]);

    if (! browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
        return <span className="error">Speech recognition not supported</span>;
    }

    return <span className="transcript">{transcript}</span>;
};

const options = {
    autoStart: false,
    continuous: false
};

export default SpeechRecognition(options)(App);
```

I wrote some tests to emulate both browsers that support speech recognition and browsers that don't:

```
// src/App.spec.js
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// Generate a mock SpeechRecognition HOC with the given props
function mockSpeechRecognition(mockProps) {
    return function(options) {
        return function(WrappedComponent) {
            return function(props) {
                return (
                    <WrappedComponent 
                        {...props}
                        {...mockProps}
                        recognition={{}}
                    />
                );
            };
        };
    };
}

describe('App component', () => {

    beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());

    it('should show an error when speech recognition is not supported', () => {
        jest.mock('react-speech-recognition', () => mockSpeechRecognition({
            browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: false
        }));

        const App = require('./App').default;
        const wrapper = mount(<App />);

        expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants('.error');
        expect(wrapper.find('.error'))
            .to.have.text('Speech recognition not supported');
    });

    it('should show the transcript when speech recognition is supported', () => {
        jest.mock('react-speech-recognition', () => mockSpeechRecognition({
            browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: true,
            transcript: 'foo'
        }));

        const App = require('./App').default;
        const wrapper = mount(<App />);

        expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants('.transcript');
        expect(wrapper.find('.transcript')).to.have.text('foo');
    });

});
```

When I run these tests, I get an ["Invalid hook call" error](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) that causes the tests to fail:

```
  ● App component › should show an error when speech recognition is not supported

    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      3 | 
      4 | const App = ({ transcript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition }) => {
    > 5 |     useEffect(() => {
        |     ^
      6 |         console.log(`transcript changed: ${transcript}`);
      7 |     }, [transcript]);
      8 | 

      at resolveDispatcher (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1465:13)
      at useEffect (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1508:20)
      at App (src/App.js:5:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17482:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18596:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21188:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24373:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24758:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21903:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:437:26)
      at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:37
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at Object.act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at wrapAct (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:13)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:423:16)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/src/mount.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.spec.js:38:25)

  ● App component › should show the transcript when speech recognition is supported

    Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

      3 | 
      4 | const App = ({ transcript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition }) => {
    > 5 |     useEffect(() => {
        |     ^
      6 |         console.log(`transcript changed: ${transcript}`);
      7 |     }, [transcript]);
      8 | 

      at resolveDispatcher (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1465:13)
      at useEffect (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1508:20)
      at App (src/App.js:5:5)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17482:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18596:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21188:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24373:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24758:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21903:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:437:26)
      at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:37
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at Object.act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at wrapAct (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:13)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:423:16)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/src/mount.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.spec.js:52:25)
```

However, there are no such errors when I run the dev server and view the page in a browser, and I can see the `useEffect` hook logging a message to the console. There are also no errors when I create a production build. I think the issue is in how I mocked out the `SpeechRecognition` HOC. The tests pass if I remove the `useEffect` hook.

This is a brand new project started with create-react-app. I only have one copy of react and react-dom and the versions match:

```
$ npm ls react react-dom
react-speech-recognition-invalid-hook-call@0.1.0 /Users/NMD/max_programming_projects/react-speech-recognition-invalid-hook-call
├── react@16.13.1 
└── react-dom@16.13.1
```

How can I fix this error in my tests?

Comment: In the end, I switched from react-speech-recognition to [react-speech-kit](https://github.com/MikeyParton/react-speech-kit) because it has a better interface that doesn't require me to do any complicated mocking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Jest:

[Invalid hook call after `jest.resetModules` for dynamic `require`s](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8987)

The bug happens when you call `jest.resetModules` or `jest.resetModuleRegistry` and then `require` your component inside your tests.

You can work around it by removing `jest.resetModules`/`jest.resetModuleRegistry` and wrapping the `require`s in calls to [`jest.isolateModules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn):

```
describe('App component', () => {

    it('should show an error when speech recognition is not supported', () => {
        jest.mock('react-speech-recognition', () => mockSpeechRecognition({
            browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: false
        }));

        jest.isolateModules(() => {
            const App = require('./App').default;
            const wrapper = mount(<App />);

            expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants('.error');
            expect(wrapper.find('.error'))
                .to.have.text('Speech recognition not supported');
        });
    });

    it('should show the transcript when speech recognition is supported', () => {
        jest.mock('react-speech-recognition', () => mockSpeechRecognition({
            browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: true,
            transcript: 'foo'
        }));

        jest.isolateModules(() => {
            const App = require('./App').default;
            const wrapper = mount(<App />);

            expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants('.transcript');
            expect(wrapper.find('.transcript')).to.have.text('foo');
        });
    });

});
```

When I run this, all tests pass and I can see the output from the `useEffect` hook:

```
 PASS  src/App.spec.js
  App component
    ✓ should show an error when speech recognition is not supported (89ms)
    ✓ should show the transcript when speech recognition is supported (6ms)

  console.log src/App.js:6
    transcript changed: undefined

  console.log src/App.js:6
    transcript changed: foo

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.577s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The solution mentioned in the issue finally brought the desired success. So I did not have to adjust all tests and can leave the global config as it is. See: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8987#issuecomment-584898030

Answer (score 3):

See [enzyme github open issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2011)

You have few options but in general you need to mock your speech recognition hoc properly by passing `browserSupportsSpeechRecognition` as shown in the below code.

**Option One**

You can mock `useEffect`. Just write code to suit your needs in useEffect mock.

```js
describe("App component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());

  it("should show an error when speech recognition is not supported", () => {

    jest.mock("react", () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual("React"),
      useEffect: (f) => f(),
    }));

    jest.mock("react-speech-recognition", () => {
      return mockSpeechRecognition({ browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: false });
    });

    const App = require("./App").default;
    const wrapper = mount(<App transcript={"hi"} />);

    expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants(".error");
    expect(wrapper.find(".error")).to.have.text(
      "Speech recognition not supported"
    );
  });
```

**Option Two**

You do not actually need to mock speech recognition hoc at all. It is an overhead. The library guys will do their testing themselves. You can do a named export of `App` and import it and write regular tests.

```js
describe("App component - no mock", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());

  it("should show an error when speech recognition is not supported", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <App browserSupportsSpeechRecognition={false} transcript={"hi"} />
    );

    expect(wrapper).to.contain.exactly(1).descendants(".error");
    expect(wrapper.find(".error")).to.have.text(
      "Speech recognition not supported"
    );
  });

  it("should NOT show an error when speech recognition is not supported", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <App browserSupportsSpeechRecognition={true} transcript={"hi"} />
    );

    expect(wrapper).does.not.contain.descendants(".error");
    // expect(wrapper.find(".error")).to.have.text(
    //   "Speech recognition not supported"
    // );
  });
});
```

**Option Three**

Use react testing library instead of enzyme.

---

*Above tests are run locally and they pass*

**References:**

- Info on [how to mock a hoc](https://devblog.xero.com/mocking-a-react-higher-order-component-hoc-with-jest-mock-fd59d5a20a97) with jest
- testing hooks [using react testing library](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-guide-to-testing-react-hooks-fa584c415407/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems a little strange to mock out `useEffect`; I don't need to mock React features in any of my other tests, so why here? I'd also prefer not to do option #2 because I don't like changing my code just for testing; that's a bit of a code smell to me. Ultimately, this issue looks like it was caused by a [bug in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8987). I wrote an answer that describes one workaround, but other people may prefer your suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try mock `SpeechRecognition` following way?

```js
jest.mock('react-speech-recognition', () => ({
  __esModule: true, 
  default: mockSpeechRecognition({
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: false
  })
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave it a try but I'm still getting the invalid hook call errors.